# Flutter: Android Studio not found at /Applications/Contents

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-sdk-tools

After installing flutter, when I run

I think I have messed up my Mac regarding Android Studio when I run
Flutter doctor reports it says Android Studio not found like below

```
Android Studio not found at /Applications/Contents
```

Flutter doctor -v

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: try this flutter config --android-studio-dir=
Let me know here if it didn't work

Answer (score 51):

Please run `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Comment: Can you @Rody please explain what this command does?

Comment: Solved on Mac M1 Pro .. Thanks

Comment: Solved on Mac M2 Pro as well.. Thanks

Comment: solved it on Mac mini M1 after fresh install (fultter.dev get started manual) after failed with path "/Users/<my username>/Library/Android/sdk"

Comment: worked on my Mac

Comment: Worked on my M1 Mac.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that when you install Android Studio with JetBrains toolbox, the pwd is different, mine was at "Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app/Contents"

So, to solve it:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Users/<$YOUR_USER>/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app/Contents
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Akshay says run `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Application/Android\ Studio.app`. I got the same problem when i ran the config command this way: `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/Application/`