# android studio not found at C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudio/Contents

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio, dart

could you please help me
I found this problem when I open VMWARE to get mac system

I use flutter to build my app in android studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duZNn.png)

Comment: Why there is a slash (`.../Contents`) instead of backslash in address?

Comment: I don't this is first time with android studio in mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this;

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir='C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio'
```

Also I found same issues this link ;

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the *mac system* reference, but your path is obviously `Windows`, I understand that you did not mean `macOS`?

For people like me looking for a `macOS` answer, I found the solution on my own after reflecting what the `Windows` path in the solution above would be on my Mac and come up with that:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="/Applications/Android Studio.app"
```

I wanted to create a question but found this similar question in the `Ask a public question` form : [Flutter: Android Studio not found at /Applications/Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022460/flutter-android-studio-not-found-at-applications-contents)

My error was `Android Studio not found at /Users/<user id>/Library/Android/sdk/Contents` as I misconfigured the path at first ...